# How to merge two rich text cells that each contain URLs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with multiple rich text cells that contain different formatting, mainly bold and hyperlinked text. I now want to combine the cells into one cell that contains all of the contents of each cell. There aren't that many, so I'm willing to put in some manual effort by way of specifying two cells at a time, rather than a range that combines them.

My current doesn't fail when only one URL is present in, say, two cells, but the output isn't correct. And when there are more than two URLs separated by "; ", it does fail.

So far I've tried the following (I recognize it's rudimentary, but I'm just trying to create something quick, haha):

```
function iterateCells() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetRange = sheet.getRange("J79")
  var sheetRange2 = sheet.getRange("K79")
  var numRows = sheetRange.getNumRows()
  var numCols = sheetRange.getNumColumns()
  var numRows2 = sheetRange2.getNumRows()
  var numCols2 = sheetRange2.getNumColumns()

  // Join on "; " to differentiate between the cells' texts
  var newText = sheetRange.getCell(1, 1).getValue() + "; " + sheetRange2.getCell(1, 1).getValue()

  var newRichText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(newText)

  var globalOffset = 0; // Should max out at len(newText) -- Necessary due to two for loops starting at k = 0, so need to offset for the second one.

  // First Cell
  for (var i = 1; i <= numCols; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= numRows; j++) {
      var cell = sheetRange.getCell(j, i)
      var currentRichTextCellValues = cell.getRichTextValue().getRuns();

      // For each piece of rich text in the given cell.
      for (var k = 0; k < currentRichTextCellValues.length; k++) {
        currentRunText = currentRichTextCellValues[k].getText()
        firstOffset = currentRichTextCellValues[k].getStartIndex();

        // Build the new rich text with text set to be that of the existing cell with whatever formatting the existing portion of the cell has.
        newRichText.setTextStyle(globalOffset, globalOffset + currentRunText.length, currentRichTextCellValues[k].getTextStyle())

        // Check if there exists a URL.
        // If so, set the URL.       
        potentialUrl = currentRichTextCellValues[k].getLinkUrl()
        if (potentialUrl) {
          newRichText.setLinkUrl(globalOffset, globalOffset + currentRunText.length, potentialUrl)
        }

        globalOffset += firstOffset;
      }
    }
  }

  // Second Cell
  for (var i = 1; i <= numCols2; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= numRows2; j++) {
      var cell = sheetRange2.getCell(j, i)
      var currentRichTextCellValues = cell.getRichTextValue().getRuns();

      // For each piece of rich text in the given cell.
      for (var k = 0; k < currentRichTextCellValues.length; k++) {
        currentRunText = currentRichTextCellValues[k].getText()
        secondOffset = currentRichTextCellValues[k].getStartIndex();

        // Build the new rich text with text set to be that of the existing cell with whatever formatting the existing portion of the cell has.
        newRichText.setTextStyle(globalOffset, globalOffset + currentRunText.length, currentRichTextCellValues[k].getTextStyle())

        // Check if there exists a URL.
        // If so, set the URL.         
        potentialUrl = currentRichTextCellValues[k].getLinkUrl()
        if (potentialUrl) {
          newRichText.setLinkUrl(globalOffset, globalOffset + currentRunText.length, potentialUrl)
        }

        globalOffset += secondOffset;

      }
    }
  }

  // Once done, overwrite the cell contents.
  sheet.getRange("L79").setRichTextValue(newRichText.build())
}
```

The output can be found here: [image]

The formatting is off, but it does merge the two cells to an extent based on the current logic.

Is it possible to get some insight into what's causing this weird formatting, and what I should fix to allow it to correctly format as well as not fail for multiple URLs in a cell? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of merging rich text with links.  Where URL and finally have a link.

[image]

```
function mergeRichText() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    let range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,3);
    let text = range.getRichTextValues()[0];
    // remove the first to start the merge
    let first = text.shift();
    let result = first.getText();
    // merge all text into one
    text.forEach( next => result = result+"; "+next.getText());
    // put the first back into first place
    text.unshift(first);
    let richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
                      .setText(result);
    let start = 0;
    let end = 0;
    text.forEach( next => {
        let runs = next.getRuns();
        runs.forEach( run => {
            richText = richText.setTextStyle(start+run.getStartIndex(),start+run.getEndIndex(),run.getTextStyle());
            if( run.getLinkUrl() ) {
              richText = richText.setLinkUrl(start+run.getStartIndex(),start+run.getEndIndex(),run.getLinkUrl());
            }
            end = run.getEndIndex();
          }
        );
        start = start+end+2;  // increase to 2
      }
    );
    range = sheet.getRange(2,1);
    range.setRichTextValue(richText.build());
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, wow, wow! This perfectly solved it! Thank you SO much for taking the time break this down and solve this, I'm extremely grateful! You've saved me a heap of time with your ingenuity!

Comment: Hi @TheWizEd! I've a quick followup question: For some reason, text that's one character long and is hyperlinked seems to have some formatting. Do you have any insight as to why this might be? Here's an image illustrating what I'm seeing: https://ibb.co/JFqfmH3

-- I should note that I changed the joining text from `" "` to `"; "`, so don't be alarmed that that's there, haha.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Then you have increased the length of the text and you need to adjust `start` as shown above.

Comment: Aha, that did it! Thank you for such a quick yet insightful reply! I had surmised that perhaps something to do with offsets or indices was at play, but didn't see that the `start` value was at the core of it! Thank you very much yet again, you've been an incredible help!